# splitting continuous data in data.frame

Tags: r, split

My data structure is

```
id value1 value2
1  0.12   1
2  0.09   0
3  0.05   0
4  0.65   1
5  0.68   0
...
```

I need to split data by using `value1`, such that 0< value1 <=0.2 == 1 or 0.2 < value1 <=0.4 == 2... (maximum `value1` is 1 and minimum `value1` is 0)

My point is that I would like to utilize `value1` range as a reference of splitting.

So, I would expect that result.

```
id value1 value2 group
1  0.12   1      1 (because value1 is range of 0~0.2)
2  0.09   0      1 (because value1 is range of 0~0.2)
3  0.05   0      1 (because value1 is range of 0~0.2)
4  0.65   1      4 (because value1 is range of 0.6~0.8)
5  0.68   0      4 (because value1 is range of 0.6~0.8)
...
```

Group vector cannot have value 2 or 3. This is because `value1` did not include range of 0.2~0.4 and 0.4~0.6.

Also, I need to calculate ratio of `value2` factor by group.

According to the above data, `group1` is consist of 33.33% 1 and 66.66% 0. Also, `group4` is consist of 50% 1 and 50% 0.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: There are lot of spelling errors in your question. You should do spell check as basic netiquette. Also, it's always good to state what all have you tried till now. Stackoverflow is not a place to get your code written for you..

Comment: OK. I got it. In next time I would consider your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `cut` function. First create some example data:

```
dd = data.frame(id = 1:20, value1=runif(20))
```

Next, define the break points and divide up `value1`

```
cuts = cut(dd$value1, breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.2))
```

then convert cuts to numeric (using some factor magic), to get what you want:

```
as.numeric(cuts)
```

So

```
dd$group = as.numeric(cut(dd$value1, breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.2)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It is a great simple approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do following

```
DF <- read.table(text='id value1 value2
1  0.12   1
2  0.09   0
3  0.05   0
4  0.65   1
5  0.68   0', header=TRUE)

DF$group <- (DF$value1)%/%0.201 + 1

DF
##   id value1 value2 group
## 1  1   0.12      1     1
## 2  2   0.09      0     1
## 3  3   0.05      0     1
## 4  4   0.65      1     4
## 5  5   0.68      0     4

# to get % of '1' in each group
result <- aggregate(value2 ~ group, DF, function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
result
##   group    value2
## 1     1 0.3333333
## 2     4 0.5000000
```